Local, out of sync, Microsoft Edge profile in Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS have been deleted. How to recover its data from its stored temp?
I accidentally deleted a local browsing profile, not synchronized with any Microsoft account, from the Edge browser.
There where a plenty of passwords, browsing history and important favorite web pages.
How can I recover this data (accesses, history and favorite web pages) that were saved locally?
I have already taken a look at:
/usr/bin/microsoft-edge-beta, where there is no temporary data;
/home/.cache/microsoft-edge/, where there is a lot of data, but I don't know what to check to start recovering the old data...
